# Is It possible to add scrollbar with a specific part in a website?

Tags: html, css, scroll, scrollbar

```css
header  {
 position:fixed;
 background-color:#4F5467;
  top:0;
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  height:60px;
}

footer {
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
float:left;
background-color: yellow;
  width:100%;
  height:45px;
}

main {
  width:96%;
  margin-left:2%;
  margin-right:2%;
  margin-bottom: calc( 45px + 2%);
  margin-top:calc( 60px + 2%);
  background-color:red;
  margin:1px solid red;

}

body{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 background-color:#edf1f5;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <header>
    </header>
    <main>
      <p>from <a href="http://goldendreamrz.blogspot.in/">http://goldendreamrz.blogspot.in/</a><p>
      <h4>ramakkal medu</h4>
      <p>This is a very popular and very beautiful tourist area. This place is near the Kerala - Tamil Nadu border.
        </p>
     <p> This is really a view  point.From the top of this mountain you will obtain  an awesome view of Tamil Nadu.
       </p>
      <p>You can see the crops and plots like an awesome drawing. The other specialty of this place is the clouds and the snow.
        </p>
      <p>Most of the time this place is covered with the clouds and snows.  This mountain 
Suicide Point
have a sharp edge which has a nick name "suicide point". The People wish their death should be in a beautiful place like this, that's why  they called this place as suicide point.</p>
    </main>
    <footer>
    </footer>
  </body>  
</html>
```

In this code i'm trying to add a scrollbar with my website.i need to be to add the scrollbar associated with the main part(currently the scrollbar appears on whole part)  and hence the main part need to be displayed  with a uniform margin from all sides.

I added a model for better understand-ability about the problem[image].this is an example with following criteria(content part have uniform margin from all sides, and it's also have own scroll from top to bottom and left to right).how can i obtain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
header  {
 position:fixed;
 background-color:#4F5467;
  top:0;
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  height:60px;
}

footer {
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
float:left;
background-color: yellow;
  width:100%;
  height:45px;
}

main {
  width:96%;
  margin-left:2%;
  margin-right:2%;
  margin-bottom: calc( 45px + 2%);
  margin-top:calc( 60px + 2%);
  background-color:red;
  margin:1px solid red;
   height: 100px;
overflow-y:scroll;
}

body{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 background-color:#edf1f5;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <header>
    </header>
    <main>
      <p>from <a href="http://goldendreamrz.blogspot.in/">http://goldendreamrz.blogspot.in/</a><p>
      <h4>ramakkal medu</h4>
      <p>This is a very popular and very beautiful tourist area. This place is near the Kerala - Tamil Nadu border.
        </p>
     <p> This is really a view  point.From the top of this mountain you will obtain  an awesome view of Tamil Nadu.
       </p>
      <p>You can see the crops and plots like an awesome drawing. The other specialty of this place is the clouds and the snow.
        </p>
      <p>Most of the time this place is covered with the clouds and snows.  This mountain 
Suicide Point
have a sharp edge which has a nick name "suicide point". The People wish their death should be in a beautiful place like this, that's why  they called this place as suicide point.</p>
    </main>
    <footer>
    </footer>
  </body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give `overflow: auto;` to the desired container:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#page {
  height: 100%;
}
#header {
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
}
#content {
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
  background: grey;
  overflow: auto;
}
#footer {
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div id="header">Header</div>
  <div id="content">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```